# Merge rows dependent on Column (delete NA values)

Tags: r

I got a problem I could not find a solution yet.
I have a dataframe in R which looks like that:

```
p  v1 v2 v3  v4 v5 v6   v7 v8 v9 <- Header
V1 1  2  3   NA NA NA   NA NA NA
V2 1  2  3   NA NA NA   NA NA NA
V3 1  2  3   NA NA NA   NA NA NA
V1 NA NA NA  4  5  6    NA NA NA
V2 NA NA NA  4  5  6    NA NA NA
V3 NA NA NA  4  5  6    NA NA NA
V1 NA NA NA  NA NA NA   7  8  9
V2 NA NA NA  NA NA NA   7  8  9
V3 NA NA NA  NA NA NA   7  8  9
```

How can I merge all the rows dependent in the first coloum the get the following output:

```
V1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
V2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
V3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If your format is regular this should work: `data.frame(unique(df[1]),lapply(df[-1],na.omit))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by the first column and then get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(p) %>%
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#  p        v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8    v9
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 V1        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
#2 V2        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
#3 V3        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```